# Scrapy Pipeline loads but doesn't work

Tags: scrapy, pipeline

I have a Scrapy project that loads the pipelines but doesn't pass items to them.  Any help is appreciated.

A stripped down version of the spider:

```py
#imports
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  #RULES AND STUFF 

  def parse_item(self, response):
    '''Takes HTML response and turns it into an item ready for database.  I hope.
    '''
    #A LOT OF CODE
    return item
```

At this point printing out the item produces the anticipated result and *settings.py* is straightforward enough:

```py
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
  'mySpider.pipelines.MySpiderPipeline',
  'mySpider.pipelines.PipeCleaner',
  'mySpider.pipelines.DBWriter',
]
```

and the pipeline seems correct (sans imports):

```py
class MySpiderPipeline(object):
  def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print 'PIPELINE: got ', item['name']
    return item

class DBWriter(object):
  """Writes each item to a DB.  I hope.
  """
  def __init__(self):
    self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb'
                                        , host=settings['HOST']
                                        , port=int(settings['PORT'])
                                        , user=settings['USER']
                                        , passwd=settings['PASS']
                                        , db=settings['BASE']
                                        , cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
                                        , charset='utf8'
                                        , use_unicode=True
                                        )
    print('init DBWriter')

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print 'DBWriter process_item'
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._insert, item)
    query.addErrback(self.handle_error)
    return item

  def _insert(self, tx, item):
    print 'DBWriter _insert'
    # A LOT OF UNRELATED CODE HERE
    return item

class PipeCleaner(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print 'Cleaning these pipes.'

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print item['name'], ' is cleeeeaaaaannn!!'
    return item
```

When I run the spider, I get this output at startup:

```
Cleaning these pipes.
init DBWriter
2012-10-23 15:30:04-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: MySpiderPipeline, PipeCleaner, DBWriter
```

Unlike their **init** clauses that do print to the screen when the crawler is started, the process_item methods are not printing (or processing) anything.  I'm crossing my fingers that I've forgotten something very simple.

Comment: Can you share some log output from when the spider is actually scraping items?

Comment: I think I've found the problem (in part).  The spider class is routing data based on HTML and sending it to other methods.  Those other methods return the item, but it doesn't make it down the pipeline.

This might be worth a different question.

Answer (score 1):

```
2012-10-23 15:30:04-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: MySpiderPipeline, PipeCleaner, DBWriter
```

this line shows that your pipeline are initializing and they are ok.

problem is is your crawler class ,

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  #RULES AND STUFF 

  def parse_item(self, response):
    '''Takes HTML response and turns it into an item ready for database.  I hope.
    '''
    #A LOT OF CODE
    # before returning item , print it 
    return item
```

i think you should print an item , before returning it from **MySpider**.

Answer (score 1):

"Better late than never"

```html
#imports
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  #RULES AND STUFF 

  def parse_item(self, response):
    '''Takes HTML response and turns it into an item ready for database.  I hope.
    '''
    #A LOT OF CODE
    yield item       <------- yield instead of return
```